# how to concatenate two lists of different lengths to fill in missing values

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to add elements from one list to another list that has part of the elements but some are missing

```py
days_m = ['1','2','3']
dates = ['4-','10-','10-20','10-4','9-']
start_end = []

for f,b in itertools.zip_longest(dates, days_m, fillvalue = 'NA'):
    if len(f) < 4:
        date = f+b
        start_end.append(date)
    elif len(f) >= 4:
        start_end.append(date)
```

I expect the output to be

```py
['4-1', '10-2', '10-20', '10-4', '9-3']
```

But the actual output has been

```
['4-1', '10-2', '10-2', '10-2', '9-NA']
```

Comment: `elif len(f) >= 4:
        start_end.append(date)` you're not updating date in this branch. That explains the repeated 10-2.

Comment: and for the other "error", zip_longest consumes both lists, even the ones you're not using.

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot use `zip_longest` here. Because you mean to pick a value from the second list *only* if the length is < 4. `zip_longest` does that all the time.

Then, you're not updating `date` in the second branch.

I suggest to use `iter` on `days_m`, and iterate on it manually with `next`, with the default value of `"NA"`. Also drop the double length test as it is redundant.

And *always* use an updated version of `f`. Just concatenate to it when needed, else use as-is.

```
days_m = iter(['1','2','3'])
dates = ['4-','10-','10-20','10-4','9-']
start_end = []

for f in dates:
    if len(f) < 4:
        f += next(days_m,"NA")
    start_end.append(f)

print(start_end)
```

result:

```
['4-1', '10-2', '10-20', '10-4', '9-3']
```